# How does one target a template function in Webpack (using jade-loader for instance)

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

Currently, I am using Jade-loader in my webpack.config.js(which returns my html as a template function, of course).

```
module.exports = {
  entry: ["./app/js/index.js"],
  output: {
    path: "./dist/js",
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {test: /\.scss$/, loader: 'style!css!sass'},
      **{test: /\.jade$/,  loader: 'jade-loader'},**
      {test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader"},
      {test: /\.js$/, loader: "eslint-loader", exclude: /node_modules/},
     //image min loader
      {test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        loaders: [
          'file?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]',
          'image-webpack?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jade', '.scss']
  }
};
```

In addition, I am using a require in my index.js

```
var jade = require("../jade/index.jade");
```

The code is actually getting compiling to my bundle.js, so it is working as planned.

However, my html is not being updated. How would I be able to pull the html from my template function? Thank you!

Edit: I have created a branch specifically for this question. https://github.com/CharlieGreenman/Gulp-Webpack-build-system/tree/learning-webpack

note: I do realize that Webpack will not emit actual html files, and that it only reads js files natively.

Comment: Are you referring to generating an `index.html` file using the webpack build system?

Comment: No. After making an edit on my jade file, and typing webpack into my terminal, I would like to see that the change has been made on my browser. For instance, if I change a text from "hello world" to "hello pizza" I would like to see the text is now "hello pizza". Or simply If I am typing for the first time, I would like to see "hello world".  Full file structure can be seen here at this branch https://github.com/CharlieGreenman/Gulp-Webpack-build-system/tree/learning-webpack

Thanks again!

Comment: so, without a browser refresh? In several of my projects, it is necessary to implement both a gulp build and a webpack build.

Comment: With a browser refresh. I will include the webpack-dev-server as time goes on. Got it, so I guess what you are saying is that Webpack isn't ideal for converting from jade to html, and I should stick to gulp for this one?

Comment: It's good for jade as template functions, but it is uncommon to generate html files using the webpack compilation build process. See this issue where I talk about doctype https://github.com/webpack/jade-loader/pull/24

Comment: Ok, now I got it. Awesome, thanks!